# Is there any interactive spline fitting software?

Tags: graphing-functions, interpolation, mathematica, spline

I'd like to know if there's any software (freeware) for interactive data interpolation. What I want is to be able to visualize my data on an XY plot and drag the points to see how it affects the interpolation curve and also get XY-coordinates for that curve. 
I tried to do this in Mathematica, but it doesn't seem to have the feature of interactively modifying the input.

Comment: Try Inkscape. It has interactive curve editing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already found the solution. QtiPlot does what I want.